# foreign key mismatch - "Comment" referencing "Chellenge"

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Chellenge(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default="1",null=False)
    chellengeName = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    chellengeDesc = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
class Comment(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default="1")
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    chellenge_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Chellenge, to_field='sno', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # This one works exact time of current location
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_comment = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
```

why i getting the error django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "Comment" referencing "Chellenge" at the time of migrate?
how to solve??

Comment: Drop all migrations and re-run `makemigrations` + `migrate` should solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the  Migration File Delete exclude "**init**.py" then after run command `python manage.py makemigrations` and python `manage.py migrate`